# How to send data to particular user?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am working on application were i need to send some data to specific user without much of delay.
Actualy I have more then 1000 users who are online out of those I want to select one user and send the data to him only.

I had two solution

1.current implementation=>

So far I am using push notification for this purpose I get the user's device Id and send notification to him but problem is push notification(sending/receiving) depend on my server and GCM 
server so it get delayed sometime(I observed sometime it  gets delayed by 5 min also).

2.Not implemented=>

Another option is to run thread continuously to check any msg is arrived, if arrived check   if whether is meant for same user or not,if he is targeted user then show the data else discard .But here also problem is even if this msg dose not belong to that user one need to check the condition and then discard.

Comment: How do you have serverside implemented? Have you considered the use of websockets?

Comment: @bogumil I am using push notification(GCM) which will be sent to particular device ID(every android mobile has unique ID).I dont know anything about websockets. could you elaborate or point to any article related to websocket which can guide me to solve my problem